# Can exec() php function run programs not in the background?

Tags: php, function, xampp, exec, server-side

Is it possible to use exec() php function to execute a program on the server but not in the background but with the GUI?
I use windows 10, xampp 3.3.0 and php 8.1.1.

Thank you, Ivan

Comment: He's asking about executing at the server. Take a look at the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: If you're trying to initiate the program from a PHP script run from the webserver, it probably doesn't have any access to the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because php doesn't have access to the GUI.